# Over-release an object and the app does not crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

```
@property (retain) NSString *testString;
self.testString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"aaa"];
[self.testString retain];    
self.testString = [NSString stringWithString:@"a"];
[self.testString release];
[self.testString release];
```

Let's go line by line:

Line 2: retain count of testString = 2 
Line 3: retain count of testString = 3
Line 4: retain count of testString = 1
Line 5: retain count of testString = 0
Line 6: it should crash

Even if there's other stuff holding to `testString` in CoreFoundation, it eventually will go away. But the app never crash due to this.

Anyone could explain this? Thanks!

Comment: Not directly related to your question,but why would `[self retain];` increase _retain count_ of `testString`?

Comment: @rokjarc: it's a typo, fixed no. Thanks =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert about this, so please take this with a grain of salt. I guess that `[NSString stringWithString:@"a"]` will probably just return the literal string `@"a"`, i.e. it just returns its argument. As `@"a"` is a literal, it probably resides in constant memory and can't be deallocated (so it should be initialized with a very high retain count).

Comment: Yes I just tried replace that by `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"a", @"b"];` and it crashes right away. Thank you =).

Comment: Did you change your answer in the 5 minute window or am I totally blind? I literally posted the same thing 5 minutes later...

Comment: @Matthias: I mis-clicked, MrMage got it first so I think it's fair to accept his answer. Upvoted you though.

Comment: actually he deserves all the upvotes. He was faster. I'm just wondering if his answer was edited or if I stopped reading at "I am not an expert" ^^

Comment: I did not edit my answer, but I also upvoted yours for the actual example.

Answer (score 5):

see this code and its log:

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"a"];
NSString *string2= @"a";
NSLog(@"String1: %p", string1);
NSLog(@"String2: %p", string2);

2012-03-22 13:21:49.433 TableDemo[37385:f803] String1: 0x5860
2012-03-22 13:21:49.434 TableDemo[37385:f803] String2: 0x5860
```

as you see `[NSString stringWithString:@"a"];` doesn't create a new string, it uses the string literal @"a". And string literals can't be deallocated.

Try your code with `NSMutableString` and you will see a crash.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSString stringWithString:@"a"]` returns an autoreleased object. That means "the true" retain count is 2 not 1 in line 4. In line 6 you are overreleasing your variable but the crash will happen later - on the autorelease pool drain.